# DWR 3.0.2 Spring 5.1.7 Upgrade 'You must include DWR engine before including this file'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere, dwr

Environment

```
Websphere 8.5.5.11
JDK 1.8
DWR
SpringMVC
Oracle DBMS
```

We recently upgraded our project, and make updates from

```
spring.jar,
spring-web.jar,
spring-webmvc.jar
dwr.jar
```

upgraded to

```
spring version 5.1.7
dwr version 3.0.2
```

We started facing multiple issues

```
1. DWR servlet didn't get initialized properly; and complains about Duplicate name found while loading the context, and another problem
   our web.xml trying to inialize both servlets i.e. DispacterServlet and DwrSpringServlet
2. After removing spring, spring-web and spring-webmvc and upgrading to latest versions; 
   web project during compilation and loading complains about missing classes; 
   spcially one of the .forName methods called during DWR inialization i.e.

   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava.......

3. engine.js not found where it supposed to be i.e. this error being thrown
   'You must include DWR engine before including this file'.
```

You can find the answers to above in answers section.

Answer (score 0):

Environment

```
Websphere 8.5.5.11
JDK 1.8
DWR
SpringMVC
Oracle DBMS
```

1. You need to strictly follow these http://www.butterdev.com/category/dwr/ examples to configure DWR and Spring (either MVC or non MVC) in web.xml and spring-servlet.xml
       and you must load/configure one servlet only.
       Duplicate name not found problem was happening due to spring-servlet.xml getting loaded twice;
       this post https://www.conqtech.com/blog/?p=85 help to resolve the problem.
2. You have to include all the jars below.

   ```
   spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
   spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   dwr-3.0.2.jar
   spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
   ```
3. They (DWR) team; made a change so that engine.js file should be declared/imported before your remoting referenced .js files in your jsp/html pages.
       This post help to resolve the problem;
       https://readthefuckingmanual.net/error/4678/Error-You-must-include-DWR-engine-before-including-this-file.

In addition to all the coding tips above; you must have to define SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as below even you have one already defined.

```
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property value="true" name="alwaysUseFullPath"></property> 
<property name="mappings">
  <props> 
    <prop key="/dwr/**/*">dwrController</prop>     
    <prop key="/interface/**">dwrController</prop> 
  </props>
</property> 
</bean>
```

And we followed below examples to fix the above problems;

http://www.butterdev.com/category/dwr/

We did faced some other compilation issues; but they are common to understand and resolve.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

late response but resolved similar problem, may help others. The short answer is that Spring 5 and DWR 3.0.1 are not compatible. DWR 3.0.1 is using old class from Sprig 3 which is causing problem, you can switch to DWR 3.0.2 and try with it.